# Outputting CAPTCHA response to Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, captcha

I'm running through testing of CAPTCHA and it's responses, and I was trying to find a way to see if I could get the response outputted to a Chrome Extension.

**Ex:** I login to web page, solve CAPTCHA, and the JSON response outputted by the CAPTCHA is shown to me. It could be shown within a Chrome Extension or other page.

**What I know:** The CAPTCHA response comes from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/userverify?k and produces a sort of JSON output with ["uvresp","XXX",1, 120].

Is there anyway to get that JSON response outputted in a way I can easily visually debug it?

Comment: there are many chrome extensions that are made for editing json haven't tried them out though also try chrome developer tools

Comment: @AaronRabinowitz Not really looking to edit JSON, that I can do with external programs. I just want the JSON to be outputted more visibly once I solve the CAPTCHA's themselves. Chrome Dev Tools has worked too, but I have to dig too far in to find what I need that I feel might be more easy to surface.